# failed to update store for object type *libnetwork.endpointCnt: Key not found in store

Tags: docker, docker-build

I had this error while building the created docker file. It happens at the stage of creating the work-directory(WORKDIR)

i did tried to restart the docker service , but it doesnot help me either!

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

FROM python:3.5

RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt

ADD . /app

CMD["python","app/hello.py"]
```

Comment: I have a feeling mine happens because I'm running containerd too.

Answer (score 56):

Restart docker deamon would fix it.

For ubuntu:

`sudo service docker restart`

Comment: almost gave myself a heart attack

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are in a wrong order of execution, the *ADD* should come **before** RUN pip. Using another **FROM** in your image basically says that you are using the last one. So your *Dockerfile* should look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get upgrade python3
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Using the tag :latest will bring the latest stable version. The other three *RUN* commands is to install python packages and dependencies. Now, using *COPY*, everything on the same folder as your *Dockerfile* will be on **app** folder, and THEN the *WORKDIR* comes, to set your container starting point.

Using python2

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Comment: Which Dockerfile are you using?

Comment: From my answer, which Dockerfile are you using?

Comment: FROM ubuntu:16.04


RUN apt-get update
RUN mkdir /cop
WORKDIR /cop
RUN apt-get update

FROM python:3.5

ADD requirements.txt /cop/
RUN pip install -r  cop/requirements.txt
ADD . /cop
CMD ["python","cop/app.py"]                                                                                                                                   .....                                                                                                                                                    ....this is the format which is used

Comment: Use one of my answers. Your script will not work because it has two FROM's command

Comment: Thanks for your help,I got an output by the way which i mentioned above and the error occurred reason is found out. It happens because of the command which i used to build is in wrong format.

Comment: @mvk1312, can you assign as the answer? It might help others :)

Comment: yeah sure.it happens because the format for run the image was incorrect . thats why is returns to that mentioned error.And more over thanks for your help and support. the right format is "   docker run  -d  app.py "

Comment: You can always check if you Docker file is wrong by simply typing, "docker run alpine" and see if you still get the same issue.  If you get the same error there is an issue with Docker engine and you probably need to restart Docker engine.